# Как установить компонент, имея только pas (D2006)?

Tags: delphi

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли установить компонент, имея только pas? Если можно, то как? У меня Turbo Delphi Professional (урезанная D2006).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте dpk, добавьте туда этот pas и Install...

ЗЫ В D7 есть кнопка Component-Install component, может у вас тоже такая есть, поищите...